# Enabling Disabling TextField on the fly

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs-4, I want to enable/disable textfield on the fly depending upon data being loaded.

I tried setting **disabled** and **readOnly** property to true/false whenever needed but it doesn't seem to get applied.

Is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the [`setDisabled`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-setReadOnly) and [`setReadOnly`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-setDisabled) methods on the `TextField` to manipulate those properties after the field is created.

Comment: Thanks JohnyHK, above is correct we can have other solution i.e. using enable() and disable() methods, they work fine